# Intent issue for android

Tags: android

I know this has been asked before but the solutions here are not helping. My problem exists in the getView method at the bottom of my ImageAndTextAdapter class. I am getting the following error when I create a new intent:

***"The Constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){} Class ) is undefined."***

MenuCells exists and is also in the manifest file.

**ImageAndTextAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAndTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private String[] mStrings;
private TypedArray mIcons;

private int mViewResourceId;

public ImageAndTextAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
        String[] strings, TypedArray icons) {
    super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mStrings = strings;
    mIcons = icons;

    mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mStrings.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mStrings[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_icon);
    iv.setImageDrawable(mIcons.getDrawable(position));

    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);
    tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             ****THE ERROR GETS THROWN AT THIS LINE****
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuCells.class);
             intent.putExtra("CELL_NAME", mStrings[position]);
                         startActivity(intent);


        }

    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

**MENU_CELLS.java**

```
package com.laerdalsun;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MenuCells extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras!=null) {
           String value = extras.getString("CELL_NAME");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `this` refers to the `OnClickListener` but you need a `Context`. Create a member variable and assign it to the `Context` you pass to your constructor

```
  public class ImageAndTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

     private LayoutInflater mInflater;

     private String[] mStrings;
     private TypedArray mIcons;

     private int mViewResourceId;
     Context c;          // create the variable

public ImageAndTextAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
        String[] strings, TypedArray icons) {
    super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);
    c = ctx;          // assign it here
    // other code
```

and use the `Context` variable you created

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

         ****THE ERROR GETS THROWN AT THIS LINE****
         Intent intent = new Intent(c, MenuCells.class);   // and use it here
```

you will also need to change

```
startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
c.startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit**

Just as the error in your comment says

```
startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
```

So add that flag and your code will look more like

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(c, MenuCells.class);
 intent.putExtra("CELL_NAME", mStrings[position]);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   // this line
 c.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue. Without logcat and relevant code I couldn't tell you why. There could be so many reasons.

Comment: The error code:

11-07 14:36:10.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3675): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted except in a new post. Anyway, it was a simple one so see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
****THE ERROR GETS THROWN AT THIS LINE****
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuCells.class);
intent.putExtra("CELL_NAME", mStrings[position]);
startActivity(intent);
```

Check the `Intent` constructor, change `this` with the actual context, 
also you need to invoke `startActivity(intent)` on the context it self.

Answer (score 0):

to create your intent you need to pass in a context, the error says you're trying to pass in an `OnClickListener`, which in the context of where you're doing it is `this`

modify your adapter a bit

```
private Context context;
public ImageAndTextAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
        String[] strings, TypedArray icons) {
    super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mStrings = strings;
    mIcons = icons;
    context = ctx;
    mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
}
```

just change your intent constructor to this `Intent intent = new Intent(context, MenuCells.class);`